# Prevent backup of iPhone on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, iphone, backup

I don't want to back up my iPhone in any way; not to my Mac, and not to iCloud. However, it seems the backup to macOS is forced whenever I connect my iPhone to my Mac, since I have opted out of iCloud backups. The dialogs are all grayed out and the process starts without my consent:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I don’t believe this can be disabled at all.  Even if the buttons weren’t grayed out, your options are “to back up” and “to back up.”  If you notice, you said you don’t back up to the cloud so the selected option is to backup locally.

Comment: Perhaps lock the folder that iTunes backup to? `sudo chflags sappnd,schg,uappnd,uchg ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/`

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down to the Options section, and uncheck "Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected", does that help?

Comment: Under Catalina 10.16.7, this doesn't help even if you uncheck the "Automatically sync" box. The next time the iPhone is connected, the checkbox is already selected and syncing proceeds without user action.